# How do I get Vim to test if user input is an integer?

Tags: integer, vim

I'm sure this is probably a simple problem, but I'm stuck. I need to write a small Vim scripting program that asks for input from the user. If the user enters an integer then the program continues. If they don't then the program loops back and asks them to retry. If they enter 'X' the program quits. How do I verify that the user has entered an integer?

Answer (score 12):

The other answers already offer good solutions; I'd just like to add the more general verification with a regular expression for completeness:

```
if input =~# '^\d\+$'
    echo "input is a number"
endif
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `type()` function:

```
if type(myvar) == type(0)
  echo "myvar is a number"
endif
```

See `:h type()`.

Comment: This won't work if by "user input" the OP is referring to the `input()` function, because that returns a String.